# How to open feedDialog or ShareDialog of facebook in Windows Store App 8.1

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Store App in which I need to publish some message and image on user's profile. Using WebAuthenticationBroker I have allowed the user to login and it returns a token but then I want to open Feed Dialog. How can I achieve this? Using graph API or any other third party SDK?

Comment: This SDK has some information and samples.  When in doubt consult the facebook API Documentation.

http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/

Comment: Tried this one but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. There is no direct library which can get this task done but it can be achieved using WebAuthenticationBroker. I just have to pass the appid in url which is permitted to publish on facebook. Using it when post is published our app is once again activated without affecting the flow. Maybe it helps someone like me who is looking for solution to it.